# JavaScript handling and event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

This is within the context of an edge extension but it will work with Standard JavaScript.

The extension must;

`1` Be able to recognise when a new tab is opened.

`2` Replace the new tab with a designated URL rather than `about:blank` etc.

`3` Have links that appear in popups open within the active tab, not a new one.

I have this JavaScript;

```js
function handleCreated(tab) {
    var newTabURL = {url: ''};
    browser.tabs.update(newTabURL);
}
browser.tabs.onCreated.addListener(handleCreated);
```

as an example. It does replace the current tab with google but only when a link in the popup is clicked. The link from the popup should be what replaces the active tab OR if the user creates a new tab it should be replaced with `mycompany.com/newtab.html`, for example.

I've got an unpackaged example with everything so you can see all of the code. To use this you must first enable developer options in MS Edge ([Here's how](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/adding-and-removing-extensions)), then you can load the extension.

The extension in its current state has code notes and explains within the UI. You can grab the extension in its current form [from this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vLCTBS718NLsiBF9Og_UQsDXoVxb3vv5). You'll just need to download and unzip then `load folder` within edge. I figured this is easier than me posting all of the code as you can better see how elements interact with each other.

So in summary;

`1` The New Tab should open with the custom URL `https://mycompany.com/newtab.html`.

`2` Typing `Google` should redirect to `https://gooogle.co.uk`. (Adding word shortcuts with JS in the address bar)

`3` Links opened from the popup should replace the active tab that the popup is available over and not open in new tabs.

It works a little bit, I'm just struggling to get the new tab function to work. This isn't intended for the MS store so the policies aren't relevant.

[Download the zipped extension folder here.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vLCTBS718NLsiBF9Og_UQsDXoVxb3vv5)

Comment: As I already informed you in thread below. It looks like MS Edge opens the link in a new tab, If the link is placed inside an extension. At present, I did not get any way to change this behavior. Due to this reason we are not able to open link in current tab. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/d1d2fc43-b4e0-4eaa-b7fc-98b07cf1cdb8/opening-links-from-the-extension-popup-in-the-active-tab?forum=ieextensiondevelopment

Comment: It can actually be done with JavaScript, so you're wrong. Not as tricky as I'd expected. I just didn't know if it would work via a popup :)

Answer (score 0):

MS Edge opens links from a popup in a new tab by default, and this tab isn't active.

If for example you had;

```html
<a href="https://google.co.uk"><p>Visit Google</p></a>
```

the URL would open in a new tab. To open the URL in the tab that is active within the Edge browser you can instead do the following, so it is actually possible.

`1` Place the element in a DIV, for example `linked content` and use `<div id="linkedcontent>` within your HTML.

`2` Place the content that should trigger the new tab within the DIV.

`3` Use the following JavaScript to `getElementByID` and then use `.onclick` to replace the current browser window.

```js
document.getElementById("linkedcontent").onclick = function() {
  var LinkedContent = {url: 'https://google.com'};
    browser.tabs.update(LinkedContent);
};
```

This will then result in the browser window being replaced by the URL specified. In my example it's `https://google.com`. If you need to do this multiple times just duplicate the code and change the `DIV id` to something unique for each and reflect this in the JavaScript too.

Comment: Did a test, As you had mentioned in your previous post. If we put a link inside DIV then Edge is not recognize the link and show it as a text. How it can solve the issue?  Testing result :- https://i.postimg.cc/0QTpC2vy/7.png

Comment: I'd recommend just styling it to look like one or linking via icons. This is the best workaround I've managed to find. Take a look at [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1d1P37okRLO4X1cIpY01O-ilVDqygyU5k) updated version. There's only one issue remaining.